# choose between tcp "long" connection and "short" connection for internal service

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I got an app that web server re-direct some requests to backend servers, and the backend servers(Linux) will do complicated computations and response to web server.
For the tcp socket connection management between web server and backend server, i think there are two basic strategy:

1. "short" connection: that is, one connection per request. This seems very easy for socket management and simplify the whole program structure. After **accept**, we just get some thread to process the request and finally **close** this socket.
2. "long" connection: that is, for one tcp connection, there could be multi request one by one. It seems this strategy could make better use of socket resource and bring some performance improvement(i am not quite sure). **BUT** it seems this brings a lot of complexity than "short" connection. For example, since now socket fd may be used by multi-threads, synchronization must be involved. and there are more, socket failure process, message sequence...

Is there any suggestions for these two strategies?

**UPDATE:**, @SargeATM 's answer remind me that i should tell more about the backend service.
Each request is kind of context-free. Backend service can do calculation based on one single request message. It seems to be sth. stateless.

Answer (score 3):

Without getting into the architecture of the backend which I think heavily influences this decision, I prefer short connections for stateless "quick" request/response type traffic and long connections for stateful protocols like a synchronization or file transfer.

I know there is some tcp overhead for establishing a new connection (if it isn't local host) but that has never been anything I have had to optimize in my applications.

Ok I will get a little into architecture since this is important. I always use threads not per request but by function. So I would have a thread that listened on the socket. Another thread that read packets off of all the active connections and another thread doing the backend calculations and a last thread saving to a database if needed. This keep things clean and simple. Easy to measure slow spots, maintain, and to optimize later when needed if needed.

Answer (score 0):

What about a third option... *no connection!*

If your job description and job results are both of small size, UDP sockets may be a good idea. You have even less resources to manage, as there's no need to bound the request/response to a file descriptor, which give you some flexibility for the future. Imagine you have more backend services and would like to do some load balancing – a busy service can send the job to another one with UDP address of job submitter. The latter just waits for the result and doesn't care where you performed the task.

Obviously you'd have to deal with lost, duplicated and out of order packets, but as a reward you don't have to deal with broken connections. Out of order packets are probably not a big deal if you can fit the request and response in one UDP message, duplication can be taken care of by some job ids, and lost packet... well, they can be simply resent ;-)

Consider this!

Comment: thanks. i never thought this since i am just following legacy code structure. But i am afraid most request cannot fit in one UDP message. I will keep your strategy in mind~

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are right.

The biggest problem with persistent connections will be making sure that app got "clean" connection from pool. Without any garbage left of data from another request.

There are a lot of ways to deal with that problem, but at the end it is better to close() tainted connection and open new one than trying to clean it...